static self-consistent calculations
How is the static self-consistent calculations different from standard self consistent field calculations? Please also explain this in context of other type of calculations e.g. single shot.

Please, check here.

I've only seen this used in low-quality work, where it is often ambiguous. I have always assumed it to mean fixing the atoms, usually when the atoms were relaxed with a different method previously, in which case your interpretation of geometry optimisation and band-structure is correct - but I could be wrong.

Thanks Phil for useful comment and @Camps for informing.
